# How can I change the size of a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I change the size of a 2d array without rearranging the numbers in an array mainly using for loops and only built in methods?
For example, {{4,5,6,7,10}, {8,4,3,9,13}} to become {{4}, {5,6}, {7,10,8}, {4,3,9,13}}.

I tried making the 2d array into two separate parts then adding it back to a new 2d array. I'm not sure how I would create the second 2d array.

Comment: @jvvgg, it's recommended to write for loops to handle this scenario for easier maintenance. If you prefer the stream/collect, then i have added an unrecommended answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  Here is one that works for any triangular number
of elements that originate in a 2D array.

First, flatten them all into a single array.

```
int[] oneD = Arrays.stream(src).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```

Then reversing the length which should be `k` where `k =  n(n+1)/2` the
number of rows would be  the following. And the 2D result is partially allocated.

```
int rows = (int)(Math.sqrt(2*oneD.length + .25) -.5);
int[][] dest = new int[rows][];
```

Now it's just a matter of copying from the `oneD` array to the destination.

```
for (int i = 0, s = 0, e = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    dest[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(oneD, s, e );
    s = e;
    e += i+2;
}

for (int[] arr : dest) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Prints

```
[4]
[5, 6]
[7, 10, 8]
[4, 3, 9, 13]
```

Comment: Good answer. I could not arrive at the Math.sqrt's `+.25) - .5`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I recommend you use `List<List<Integer>>`, for example ArrayList, insted of pure arrays, and you can set your aggregations like this:

```
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

    //  add {4,5,6,7,10} to array, result = {{4,5,6,7,10}}
    values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7,10));
    matrix.add(values);

    //  add {8,4,3,9,13} to last array, result = {{4,5,6,7,10}, {8,4,3,9,13}}
    values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8,4,3,9,13));
    matrix.add(values);

    System.out.println("start="+ matrix);

    //  reset array or you can use another array to copy
    matrix = new ArrayList<>();

    values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4));
    matrix.add(values);

    values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,6));
    matrix.add(values);

    values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7,10,8));
    matrix.add(values);

    values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,3,9,13));
    matrix.add(values);

    System.out.println("end="+ matrix);
```

Output:
start=[[4, 5, 6, 7, 10], [8, 4, 3, 9, 13]]
end=[[4], [5, 6], [7, 10, 8], [4, 3, 9, 13]]

Comment: I have to keep it as an array. I'm just not sure how I would.

Answer (score 0):

### A possible not-recommended solution

1. Flatten the 2d array
2. Collect with grouping on summation sequence
3. It might be improved to use single atomic counter (i am unable to think)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayResize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] input = new Integer[][] {{10, 11, 12 ,13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}};
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger group = new AtomicInteger(1);
        Collection<List<Integer>> out = Arrays.stream(input)
            .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(i)) // flatten
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> {
                final int currentIndex = index.getAndIncrement();
                return (group.get() * (group.get() + 1)) / 2 == currentIndex
                    ? group.incrementAndGet() // increment group if index matches the summation of the range
                    : group.get(); // return the group
            }))
            .values();
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

### output has to be any Integer array

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayResize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] input = new Integer[][] {{10, 11, 12 ,13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}};
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger group = new AtomicInteger(1);
        Integer[][] output = Arrays.stream(input)
            .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(i)) // flatten
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> {
                final int currentIndex = index.getAndIncrement();
                return (group.get() * (group.get() + 1)) / 2 == currentIndex
                    ? group.incrementAndGet() // increment group if index matches the summation of the range
                    : group.get(); // return the group
            })).values().stream() // stream collection
            .map(subgroup -> subgroup.toArray(new Integer[0])) // map subgroups to arrays
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect as list of arrays
            .toArray(new Integer[0][0]); // convert to array

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
    }
}
```

### Disclaimer

1. I would not write the above code in any of my production systems
2. At the current state, it will fail with parallel stream usage

#### Solution using index count

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayResize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] input = new Integer[][] {{10, 11, 12 ,13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19}};
        List<Integer> flattened = Arrays.stream(input).flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer[]> temporary = new ArrayList<>();
        final int count = flattened.size();
        int start = 0;
        int range = 1;
        while (start < count) {
            temporary.add(flattened.subList(start, Math.min(start + range, count)).toArray(new Integer[0]));
            start += range;
            range++;
        }
        Integer[][] result = temporary.toArray(new Integer[0][0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using pure Java code (e.g. loops) and no methods at all.

```java
static int[][] toTriangle(int[][] input) {
    // Count number of values
    int valueCount = 0;
    for (int[] inputRow : input)
        valueCount += inputRow.length;
    if (valueCount == 0)
        return new int[0][0];
    
    // Determine number of result rows, and how many values that can store
    int resultRowCount = 0, resultCount = 0;
    for (int row = 0; resultCount < valueCount; row++) {
        resultRowCount++;
        resultCount += row + 1;
    }
    int oversize = resultCount - valueCount;
    
    // Build result jagged array (last row is likely truncated)
    int[][] result = new int[resultRowCount][];
    for (int row = 0; row < resultRowCount - 1; row++)
        result[row] = new int[row + 1];
    result[resultRowCount - 1] = new int[resultRowCount - oversize];
    
    // Copy values
    int inputRow = 0, inputCol = 0;
    for (int[] resultRow : result) {
        for (int i = 0; i < resultRow.length; i++) {
            while (inputCol == input[inputRow].length) {
                inputRow++;
                inputCol = 0;
            }
            resultRow[i] = input[inputRow][inputCol++];
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

*Tests*

```java
test(new int[][] {{4,5,6,7,10}, {8,4,3,9,13}});
test(new int[][] {{1,2,3,4}, {}, {5,6,7}});
```

```java
static void test(int[][] input) {
    print("Input", input);
    print("Result", toTriangle(input));
}
static void print(String label, int[][] arr) {
    System.out.println(label + ":");
    for (int[] row : arr) {
        System.out.print("  [");
        String sep = "";
        for (int val : row) {
            System.out.print(sep + val);
            sep = ", ";
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

*Outputs*

```
Input:
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 10]
  [8, 4, 3, 9, 13]
Result:
  [4]
  [5, 6]
  [7, 10, 8]
  [4, 3, 9, 13]
```

```
Input:
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
  []
  [5, 6, 7]
Result:
  [1]
  [2, 3]
  [4, 5, 6]
  [7]
```

Notice how the last row is truncated in length, since there are not enough values to fill a triangle. The second example also shows that it can handle empty sub-arrays in the input.